# Cisco Anyconnect VPN IP Address not being used to connect to Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, ssms, ip-address, vpn, azure-sql-server

I am able to connect to Azure SQL Servers by defining my IP address in the firewall rules for a server. Although due to working from home and having a dynamic IP address, this can become tedious and annoying for other databases that I have to request to get my new IP address added to to gain access.

I have connected to my company's VPN through Cisco Anyconnect VPN. Is it possible for SQL Server Management Studio to use the VPN's IP address to connect to Azure SQL Servers so I can access the server using the VPN? Currently when I'm connected to the VPN and try to connect through SSMS, my public IP address is still being used and says that my address does not have access to the server. How would I be able to configure this to use Cisco Anyconnect VPN's IP address instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to your company's VPN through Cisco Anyconnect VPN. You should add the outbound public IP address list from your company to the firewall rules for a Azure SQL Server.

You may ask your security admin for the IP lists or check your current Public IP [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) with connecting VPN connection.

Comment: But the problem is that my outbound IP address is from my own WiFi connection and not from the VPN. I can see an IP address for cisco anyconnect in my command prompt with ipconfig /all but it isn't used for any outgoing connection for SQL server

Comment: There might enable anyconnect VPN split-tunneling, read [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/anyconnect-split-tunneling-local-lan-access-split-tunneling/ta-p/4050866). You can disable it or you may consider deploying a TCP proxy to connect to SQL Database over VPN. [Here](https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/using-a-tcp-proxy-to-connect-to-sql-database-over-vpn/) is an example of connecting to SQL Database over Azure point-to-site VPN.